# How to print the values of tensors inside a while loop?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

I'm very new to tensorflow, and I couldn't figure this one out.

I have this while loop:

```
def process_tree_tf(n_child, reprs, weights, bias, embed_dim, activation = tf.nn.relu):
    n_child, reprs = n_child, reprs
    parent_idxs = generate_parents_numpy(n_child)
    loop_idx = reprs.shape[0] - 1
    loop_vars = loop_idx, reprs, parent_idxs, weights, embed_dim

    def  loop_condition(loop_ind, *_):
        return tf.greater(0, loop_idx)

    def loop_body(loop_ind, reprs, parent_idxs, weights, embed_dim):
        x = reprs[loop_ind]
        x_expanded = tf.expand_dims(x, axis=-1)
        w = weights
        out = tf.squeeze(tf.add(tf.matmul(x_expanded,w,transpose_a=True), bias))
        activated = activation(out)
        par_idx = parent_idxs[loop_ind]
        reprs = update_parent(reprs, par_idx, embed_dim, activated)
        reprs = tf.Print(reprs, [reprs]) #This doesn't work
        loop_ind = loop_ind-1
        return loop_ind, reprs, parent_idxs, weights, embed_dim

    return tf.while_loop(loop_condition, loop_body, loop_vars)
```

And I'm evaluating it this way:

```
embed_dim = 2
hidden_dim = 2
n_nodes = 4
batch = 2
reprs = np.ones((n_nodes, embed_dim+hidden_dim))
n_child = np.array([1, 1, 1, 0])
weights = np.ones((embed_dim+hidden_dim, hidden_dim))
bias = np.ones(hidden_dim)
with tf.Session() as sess:
    _, r, *_ = process_tree_tf(n_child, reprs,  weights, bias, embed_dim, activation=tf.nn.relu)
    print(r.eval())
```

I want to check the value of `reprs` inside the while loop, but `tf.Print` doesn't seem to work, and `print` just tells me it's a tensor and gives me its shape. 
How do I go about doing this?

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at this webpage: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Print

You can see that tf.Print is an identity operator with the side effect of printing data when evaluating. You should therefore use this line to print:

`reprs = tf.Print(reprs, [reprs])`

Hope this helps, and good luck!

Comment: Thank you for answering! I tried what you said, but that didn't work either. I tried using with tf.control_dependencies and that failed too.

Comment: Could you say what the output is of this:

print(reprs)
reprs_out = tf.Print(reprs, [reprs])
print(reprs_out)

Comment: This is what I get:
`Tensor("while/update_parent:0", shape=(4, 4), dtype=float64)
Tensor("while/Print:0", shape=(4, 4), dtype=float64)`

Comment: Can you use tensorboard to debug your graph? If it is not printing, there might be something wired wrongly.

Comment: I'm not familiar with tensorboard,  but I'll give it a try. Would it help if I mentioned that I got this error when trying to evaluate reprs inside the loop? `ValueError: Operation 'while/update_parent' has been marked as not fetchable.`?

Comment: I am having same issue. Unable to print the value of a tensor inside while loop even when using tf.Print() . Did you figure it out?

Answer (score 1):

The approach suggested by rmeertens is the one I think is correct. I would just add (as a response to your comments) that if something is printing "Tensor("while/update_parent:0, ...... " then that implies that that value in the graph is not being evaluated.

You are likely seeing that as the output of your "print(r.eval())" statement, NOT the tf.Print() statement.

Note that the output of tf.Print() appears in PyCharm (the IDE I am using) in red, while the output of a normal python print operation appears in black. So the tf.Print() output looks like a warning message. It could be that it is indeed printing out, but you are simply overlooking it.